# jQuery syntax order

Tags: jquery

Please pardon me as I am still a novice at jQuery and I'm more comfortable using others code than writing it myself.
My question pertains to this line, specifically:

```
$('r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(page).each(function(index, content) {
```

Is the html(page) in the correct syntax order?  How do you tell?

```
$.get('---------------/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt, success: function(data) {
        var page = $(data);

        var lessonArray= new Array();
        //loop through each element and grab the text

        $('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(page).each(function(index, content) {
            score=parseInt(content.substr(content.length - 1));
            lessonArray[index]=score;
        }); 

    allLessonsArray[name]=lessonArray;
    });
```

Edit: I'm having another problem, this time mainly due to my inexperience with jQuery.

```
userid= 17320;
courseid=4745;
allLessonsArray=script(userid, courseid);
function script(userid, courseid){


var lessonInTopicSectionArray= new Array();
lessonInTopicSectionArray['Floods, external']=376;

var allLessonsArray= new Array();
$.each(lessonInTopicSectionArray, function(name, lesson){


    lastAttempt = 0;
    url='----/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var page = $(data);

        var lessonArray= new Array();
        //loop through each element and grab the text

        $('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(page).each(function(index, content) {
            score=parseInt(content.substr(content.length - 1));
            lessonArray[index]=score;
        }); 
        alert(name);
    allLessonsArray[name]=lessonArray;  
    });
});
return allLessonsArray;
}
```

How do I return allLessonsArray from the previous loop so I can return allLessonsArray?  I'm not thoroughly understanding the object oriented aspects of jQuery, so an explanation would be nice.

Comment: They might be in the right order or the order might not even matter. It depends what you want to do. You are missing a quote in your second code block.

Comment: Thanks for the notice (the code isn't a complete snippet).
What I want to do in this case is select each r1.lastrow td.cell.c0 from the page that was opened previously, then extract the content.

Comment: @NathanLothamer `data` is the response from the server (Whole html page), are you looking for a whole page to put into a `td.cell`? if not you need to filter out the element which you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last quote in the end of the $.get url parameter ?

```
$.get('http://example.com/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt, success: function(data) {
    var page = $(data);

    var lessonArray= new Array();
    //loop through each element and grab the text

    $('r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(page).each(function(index, content) {
        score=parseInt(content.substr(content.length - 1));
        lessonArray[index]=score;
    }); 

    allLessonsArray[name]=lessonArray;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to say

```
var page = data;
```

"data" is simply the response string, it is not a jQuery object. I can not see any other problem following the logic of what you have shown us.

P.S. other answer is also correct for the quote at the end if the URL

Answer (score 0):

IF i'm guessing correctly, you are looking for this

```
$.get('http://example.com/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id=' + lesson + ' & action = reportdetail & userid = ' + userid + ' & try = ' + lastAttempt, function(data) {
    var page = $(data);

    var lessonArray = new Array();

    //loop through each element and grab the text
    page.find('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0 ').each(function(index, content) {
        score = parseInt(content.substr(content.length - 1));
        lessonArray[index] = score;
    });

    allLessonsArray[name] = lessonArray;
});​
```

P.S

<strike>I am curious to know, is there any `r1` tag in `HTML`?</strike>

Comment: Nope, no r1, just didn't include the 'tr.' .  This code was derived from notes, so not everything is accurate.  Does find get the content?